# Check if super object contains a superclass

Tags: python, python-2.7, super

I want to figure out whether a super object contains a specific super class. Since it's a complex object that takes care of a lot of things, it doesn't simply respond to `isinstance`.

```
class MyClass(MySuperClass):
    def cast_as_parent(self):
        return super(MyClass, self)

myobj = MyClass()
isinstance(myobj, MyClass) # True
isinstance(myobj, MySuperClass) # True
```

How can I implement a method `contains_class` that returns true if a `super` object contains a specific parent class? e.g.:

```
myobj_super = myobj.cast_as_parent()
isinstance(myobj_super, MySuperClass) # False (Current behavior)
contains_class(myobj_super, MySuperClass) # True
```

Comment: What's the *actual problem* you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: An object being able to 'cast' itself as its superclass. Because reasons : ) (trying to keep a consistent API)

Comment: That's a bizarre thing to do, and I don't think `super`'s API supports it. Also, that `cast_as_parent` method doesn't really do what its name says, and it'll cause surprises somewhat dual to the bugs caused by `super(self.__class__, self)`.

Comment: But to what end? If you can't replace an instance of the superclass with an instance of the subclass, you already have huge problems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I suspect you're trying to solve [entirely the wrong problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731), so could you give some more context?

Comment: Any use cases I can think of for something like this would be better solved by using `myobj` directly, constructing a new `MySuperClass` instance instead of a `super` object, or making an explicit `super` call instead of hiding it in a dynamically-dispatched method.

Comment: Please note that *"reasons"* aren't reasons.